# How to insert data into access table from two different Excel files using access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two excel files with the following columns

1st Excel file: Roll No, Student Name, age, gender 
2nd Excel file: Roll No, course, grades

From these two tables i need to add Roll No, Student Name, Course and Grades into access table

To import this data i need to load two files add particular column data using access vba.

Answer (score 0):

Link the two Excel files and create one or two queries to append the data to your table.

Comment: I cannot use link ... i need to add those using access vba

Comment: Then do that: TransferText. Look up the on-line help.